# Wi-Fi (esp8266) Point-to-Point Connection

Tags: communication, esp8266, wifi, network

Is it possible to have a point-to-point connection over Wi-Fi, similar to how an RF Module would work. No connections involved, just sending or receiving data packets to all nearby networks. I am trying to do so using some esp8266-01s modules, no encryption/handshakes needed (UDP?). Something to do with AP set broadcast messages? I am doing all this with no Wi-Fi Networks nearby, other than an esp8266 AP.

p.s. I am not looking to embed the data in the SSID's. (Unless that is the only option)

Answer (score 0):

There's no no-handshake mode in Wifi: it's truly a network protocol.

You can build ad-hoc networks, but that's it. It might totally suffice, though! You can find a few github repos when you search for "esp8266 ad hoc", so I guess people have already done that.

Comment: this wont work due to the device connection limitation of the esp8266. I am looking for this ptp connection so i can have "infinite" clients. (Provided my RX Buffer is large enough)

Comment: bad luck, being a network, not a ptp, protocol is a limitation of IEEE802.11. You might have picked the wrong type of wireless interface hardware!

Comment: Specifically picked this hardware because it is the cheapest MCU that runs MicroPython, (lol) and has wireless capability. I will probably go in the direction of a chained, or mesh network however, which can allow for hundreds of connections. Just wanted to exhaust all options before delving into programming for this topology.

Comment: Honest remark: if going for something like meshed IoT, IEEE802.11 (wifi) might really not be the kind of thing that makes your life easier! Zigbee (IEEE802.15.4) might be simpler, and more power-efficient, and it's designed with mesh networking right from the start. But you're right, if you just want *any* wireless interface, the ESP8266 is hard to beat. If you want to have zigbee, consider [one of these](https://www.digikey.de/short/0r08nqw3), I guess :)